# Mesh with 2 faces at nearly 180º angle

Tags: rendering, faces

I have this model with a very sharp angle on the edge between two faces and this is causing some rendering issues.

Is there a better way to model this sharp edge? Its not entirely flat o the x/y plane, it has some inclination.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: In real life there are no paper thin objects, constructions are rarely built that way. Maybe add some thickness there.

Comment: So just add a very small face to the start of the ramp

Answer (score 1):

Following advice from @Duarte in the comments I added thickness to the base of the model.

In case someone finds this issue the steps I used to add this extra thickness in this model were:

*In edit mode:*

- Set the view to `-z` and select all faces.
- <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> (*to extrude by `0.01`*)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> (*select all and move `.01` on the `z` axis*)

[image]